# Liferay Workflow Notification based on Approve or Reject State

Tags: liferay, workflow, liferay-6

I've implemented a simple single approval Kaleo Workflow in Liferay 6.2.

My requirement is that a Notification be sent to the User who created the Asset, when the Asset has been Approved.

The notification "*Your Request has been Approved*" is not being sent to the User who created the Asset. Below is my Workflow XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-definition xmlns="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.2.0 http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-workflow-definition_6_2_0.xsd">
    <name>Test</name>
    <version>1</version>
    <state>
        <name>Created</name>
        <metadata><![CDATA[{"transitions":{"to_pending":{"bendpoints":[],"xy":[-26,-20]},"sent":{"bendpoints":[]},"ToPending":{"bendpoints":[],"xy":[-26,-20]},"CreatorCheck":{"bendpoints":[],"xy":[-36,10]}},"xy":[63,82]}]]></metadata>
        <initial>true</initial>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>ToPending</name>
                <target>PendingTask</target>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </state>
    <task>
        <name>PendingTask</name>
        <metadata><![CDATA[{"transitions":{"Approved":{"bendpoints":[],"xy":[-36,10]},"Rejected":{"bendpoints":[]}},"xy":[220,70]}]]></metadata>
        <actions>
            <notification>
                <name>NotifyEveryone</name>
                <template>Task is in pending state.</template>
                <template-language>velocity</template-language>
                <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
            </notification>
            <notification>
                <name>RejectedNotification</name>
                <template>Your Request has been rejected!</template>
                <template-language>velocity</template-language>
                <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
                <recipients>
                    <user />
                </recipients>
                <execution-type>onExit</execution-type>
            </notification>
            <notification>
                <name>ApprovedNotification</name>
                <template>Your Request has been Approved!</template>
                <template-language>velocity</template-language>
                <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
                <recipients>
                    <user />
                </recipients>
                <execution-type>onExit</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
        <assignments>
            <roles>
                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>Portal Content Reviewer</name>
                    <auto-create>true</auto-create>
                </role>
            </roles>
        </assignments>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>Approved</name>
                <target>Approved</target>
            </transition>
            <transition>
                <name>Rejected</name>
                <target>Rejected</target>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </task>
    <state>
        <name>Approved</name>
        <metadata><![CDATA[{"terminal":true,"xy":[413,52]}]]></metadata>
        <actions>
            <action>
                <name>Approved</name>
                <script>
                <![CDATA[
                    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil
                    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants

                    WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED, workflowContext)
                ]]>
                </script>
                <script-language>groovy</script-language>
                <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
            </action>
            <notification>
                <name>newNotification1</name>
                <template>Your Request has been Approved</template>
                <template-language>text</template-language>
                <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
    </state>
    <state>
        <name>Rejected</name>
        <metadata><![CDATA[{"terminal":true,"xy":[413,144]}]]></metadata>
        <actions>
            <action>
                <name>Rejected</name>
                <script>
                <![CDATA[
                    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil
                    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants

                    WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_DENIED, workflowContext)
                ]]></script>
                <script-language>groovy</script-language>
                <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
            </action>
        </actions>
    </state>
</workflow-definition>
```

I did check the below links

1. [Designing workflows with Kaleo Designer for Java](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/lp-6-1-dgen08-designing-workflows-with-kaleo-designer-for-java-0)
2. [Use Workflow To Send Notification ONLY](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/17149270)

In the second link, Vishal has specified

*We could have following tags in <task> tag only not in <state> tag.*

If this is the case, how do I go about achieving my requirement? Can I add another Task which will send a Notification and then call the "Approve" state??

**EDIT**
Added a "Rejected" State as it was required. Also added the Notification messages for both Approved and Rejected for the User who has created the Request as pointed out by *Saleem Khan* and *Jozef Chocholacek*

Right now this is sending a Notification irrespective of whether an Asset is "Approved" or "Rejected". On "Rejection" a different message has to be sent. How do I check for whether the Asset was Approved or Rejected and send different messages?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the notification into the `<task>`, and setting `<execution-type>onExit</execution-type>` should help.

Comment: Yeah, I've added the Notification as you have suggested but now I have "Rejected" status and need to send notifications based on whether the asset was "Approved" or "Rejected". Any ideas??

Comment: Add some logic to the notification template, using e.g. `transitionName` variable - see http://www.liferay.com/de/web/igor.beslic/blog/-/blogs/workflow-in-action-kaleo-workflow-context-variables

Comment: Thanks Jozef, will implement what is explained in the link and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code to the notification in your Approve State

`<recipients>
     <user />
</recipients>`

this will send the notification to the user who has created the asset

Comment: Yup, This works. I've Updated my question. Need help for conditional notifications.

Comment: Gautham add reject notification in your rejected state, so that you can send two different messages to the user based on the state and remove RejectedNotification and ApprovedNotification from PendingTask

Comment: Notifications are not being sent in the `<states>` tag. To overcome that issue, I have implemented what Jozef Chocholacek had suggested.